# Listen for multiple clicks on a link with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following in one file called _Header which is included in all pages by the layout page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "_Header";
}

<header>
    <a id="home" href="#">MenuEditor</a>
</header>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var a = document.getElementById("home");
            a.onclick = function () {
                $("#main").load("@Url.Content("/Home/")");
                return false;
            };
        });
</script>
```

In my layout page, there is a div called #main which contains all the contents of each page and needs to be changed.

```
<div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
</div>
```

My issue is that it will change #main to the contents of /Home/ only once, but will not do it again! Is there a way to get it to keep listening after the first click?

Comment: Use delegation because you are replacing elements and so removing attached handlers

Comment: Is element with ID body (#body) the body element?

Comment: it is a div, that I badly named

Comment: So really badly named... :) Is #home element inside this DIV?

Comment: What? An anchor tag inside head section? Really??? This is absolutely not valid. Or maybe what you call head is an another DIV...

Comment: You can't have page elements in the head.

Comment: This is crazy.  Just try @roasted's answer below.  I'm 99% sure it will fix your problem.  If not, change `'#home'` to `document`

Comment: I am being very bad here. <header> not <head>. Sorry.

Comment: Is `a#home` inside `#body`?

Comment: The issue you describe doesn't fit what you are telling us about your HTML code. Provide all the relevant code then.

Comment: The answer below works, thank you. No it is not. I will rewrite the question for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document.body).on('click','#home',function(){
   $("#body").load('@Url.Content("/Home/")'); // is it '#body' or body, can be both
   return false;
});
```